# What are the minimum database privileges to run WP?

Tags: database, privileges

In my current installation, the DB user has been granted full privileges.

[image: Complete list of his privileges.]

I am pretty sure that not all of them are required to run WP, but I am not sure which privileges are definitely needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I get a 404 error from Dropbox trying to look at the image.

Comment: Image link works now.  See this Q&A for a possible solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/mysql-database-user-which-privileges-are-needed