# What permissions should i have set up for the Database User after i have Wordpress set up?

Tags: permissions

so i was reading [this on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and read this

> Never connect to the database as a superuser or as the database owner. Use always customized users with very limited privileges.

Before getting my own webserver I was using a friend's who had to set up db users for me so to make thing easier I just used the all access database owner user he gave me. the quote above was something i did when i worked on my hand built website on my local server but I plain forgot about this when I deployed my wordpress site.

Now I've already set up my WordPress website and everything is working fine. I would like to know what the minimum permissions I require for the Database User to still run WordPress ***after*** it's been installed. Particularly if there are permission differences between just making posts/uploading images, running updates of themes/plugins/wordpress core and installing new themes/plugins.

I will of cause be doing this on my local install first before doing it live so theres no need to bring up anything about extra permissions individual themes/plugins may need (i'll pick these up when they start to error for me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Database User: Which Privileges are needed?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/mysql-database-user-which-privileges-are-needed)

Answer (score 0):

According to codex,

> For normal WordPress operations, such as posting blog posts, uploading
>   media files, posting comments, creating new WordPress users and
>   installing WordPress plugins, the MySQL database user only needs data
>   read and data write privileges to the MySQL database; **SELECT, INSERT,
>   UPDATE and DELETE**.
>
> Note: Some plugins, themes and major WordPress updates might require
>   to make database structural changes, such as add new tables or change
>   the schema. In such case, before installing the plugin or updating a
>   software, you will need to temporarily allow the database user the
>   required privileges.